# Print codepath for starting method and data

Tags: aop, static-code-analysis, code-profiling

Is there a tool/method to list all function calls(codepath) for a starting point consisting of a specific method and some data(both global and function argument)?
This is a Visual Studio MFC console C++ project.
I thought of using AOP to tackle this, but it would be my first try at AOP, and would prefer a proven solution.
Additional problem for profiling is that the app has an infinite while listener and is multithreaded + "inter-process communication" (so profiler would have to pickup on other process response, and filter calls within while loop).
Is static code analysis a viable solution for this, or should i continue looking for profiling and AOP to solve this?

Comment: This question is off-topic, which is why I voted to close it. No offense meant, I hope you understand. Quote from the option offered by SO for the close vote: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._ Besides, that you are a first-time AOP user does not mean AOP is not a proven solution, only that you don't want to learn it.

Comment: I meant my solution based on AOP, not AOP itself

Comment: What difference does it make for what I just explained to you? Where is your code?